# Continous maps and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

What I want to show:

Suppose $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  is open and $\textbf{f}: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a function.
$\textbf{f}$ is continuous at $\textbf{a}$ $\iff$ for every sequence $\{$ $\textbf{x}_n$ $\}$ of points in U converging to $\textbf{a}$, we have $\textbf{f}(x_{n})$  $\rightarrow$ $\textbf{f(a)}$.

I want to know if my proof of the converse is logically correct:

Suppose for every sequence $(x_n)$ of points in U converging to $\textbf{a}$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow \textbf{f(a)}$. Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $\textbf{f}$ is not continous at $\textbf{a}$. This means that $\exists$ $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall \delta>0$ $\exists x\in U$ $:$ $||x-a||<\delta$ $\implies$ $||\textbf{f(x)-f(a)}||\geq \epsilon$. So for $\epsilon>0$, and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a sequence of points $x_n$ with the property that $||x_n-\textbf{a}||$ $< \frac{1}{n}$. By the squeeze prniciple, $x_n$ therefore converges to $\textbf{a}$. By assumption this implies that $f(x_n) \rightarrow \textbf{f(a)}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes m, your prove it is correct

Comment: Your proof is right, but the title of your question is a little bit strange.